# STL Faces and Edges

Tags: openscad

Is it possible in OpenSCAD to access faces, normals, edges and connectivity of STL geometry?

I'd like to modify the STL geometry by iterating over each face and modifying it based on some local criteria.

If this is not possible in OpenSCAD, recommendations for an open tool or library are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSCAD does not support access to the geometry in that way yet. I would suggest a library like [JSSTL](https://github.com/tonylukasavage/jsstl) to access the facets, although that will depend on the language you would like to implement your app in.